# Is it possible to hide the coefficients that are from factors in R lm()?

Tags: r, linear-regression, coefficients

I have a model with two types of many different fixed effects, and I am only interested in a few regressors and not the fixed effects themselves.  I find it easier to include the as.factor variables to have fixed effects (rather than use a within estimator).  Is it possible, however, to suppress the output of these factor coefficients?

Comment: Are you actually calling the fixed effects with `as.factor()`? As in: `lm(y~x+as.factor(f),data=df)`? Or are they already factors and you trust `lm()` to treat them as such? i.e. `lm(y~x+f,data=df)`

Comment: They are already factors and lm is treating them that way.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should work... If your model is named `m` then try this:

```
coef(m)[!names(coef(m)) %in% paste0(rep(names(m$xlevels), times=sapply(m$xlevels, length)), unlist(sapply(names(m$xlevels), function(x) m$xlevels[[x]])))]
```

It's ugly but the concept is to use the `xlevels` attribute of the `lm` object to identify coefficients that are factors and remove them from the coefficients list. The rest is just the best way I could find to get the formatting right.